File name too long when transferring to a target ext4 filesystem although it is accessible with the same filename length on a sourece ext4 filesystem
I have a file that I want to transfer from computer A to computer B via an external hard drive. All those hard drives are formatted in ext4. The file is accessible (meaning I could read it without problem) on computer A and external hard drive.
When I want to rsync the file saved on the external hard drive to computer B:
rsync: [receiver] mkstemp "/home/theuser/Documents/path/to/the/file_with_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_long_filename.pdf.LY2KGE" failed: File name too long (36)

I read in the following question and website that it is probably related to the fact that the max filename length of ext4 filesystem is 255 bytes

rsync "File name too long (36)" error for filenames with UTF-8 characters
https://winbuzzer.com/2021/06/30/filesystems-explained-whats-the-difference-between-fat32-ntfs-exfat-hfs-and-ext4-xcxwbt/

Here is my question: if the file is accessible on computer A and external hard drive implying that the filename is not a problem there, why does it become a problem when one attempts to transfer the file?

It might not be the file name itself, but the file name and path might be too long. I know that this can be a problem on Windows at least.

if you shorten the path to the file does the problem resolve itself? The linked question is only applicable to Windows not Linux it seems due to the reference to NTFS.

Thank you for you comment @Mokubai: so shortening the path does not seem to solve the problem

thank you for your comment @Ramhound: so shortening the file name with same path makes indeed the error message disappear. However, to my view, the question persists. Do you have an idea?

@ecjb - Use a shorter path

The key word here is mkstemp you can see in the error message.

The mkstemp() function shall create a regular file with a unique name derived from template and return a file descriptor for the file open for reading and writing. The application shall ensure that the string provided in template is a pathname ending with at least six trailing X characters. The mkstemp() function shall modify the contents of template by replacing six or more X characters at the end of the pathname with the same number of characters from the portable filename character set. The characters shall be chosen such that the resulting pathname does not duplicate the name of an existing file at the time of the call to mkstemp(). The mkstemp() function shall use the resulting pathname to create the file, and obtain a file descriptor for it […]

(source)
The message also contains the string file_with_very_…_very_long_filename.pdf.LY2KGE. I think this is what happened:

The original name is file_with_very_…_very_long_filename.pdf. It's not too long, yet close to the limit.
The receiving rsync used the original name to create a template for mkstemp(). The template was file_with_very_…_very_long_filename.pdf.XXXXXX.
mkstemp() tried to create a file with the name file_with_very_…_very_long_filename.pdf.LY2KGE. This name is obviously longer than the original name. It is this name that was too long and caused the failure.

Apparently, if everything went fine, rsync would eventually rename the file to the original name.
I don't know much about how rsync works under the hood, in this paragraph I'm taking an educated guess. It is very likely that rsync uses temporary names during transfers to create (or replace) target files in atomic way each. This is a known good practice. Imagine somefile is about to be created (or overwritten) and the final size is not trivially small. If rsync was writing to somefile directly, there would be a time window when the file is incomplete (or incoherent). Preparing a new complete file under a temporary name (e.g. somefile.U3RJV7 or just U3RJV7) and then moving it to the target name within the same filesystem solves this: there is nothing (or the old version) and suddenly a complete (or completely updated) file appears as somefile.
If the receiving rsync used a reasonably short fixed-length template then there would be no problem. It used the template longer than the target name, hence the problem. This may be considered a bug.
I skimmed through man 1 rsync and found no options to adjust the buggy behavior. For now it seems to me you need to use a shorter filename if you want to use rsync to transfer the file. Renaming the file back (on both ends) after the transfer should be possible.
